# Sorting alphabetically in C using strcmp

Tags: c

I am trying to sort records (structs) by their names. And  I'm using strcmp to swap to detect the alphabetical order. The swapping works fine, however it doesn't always sort the entire list. It always leaves some records in thier incorrect alphabetic order.

```
void sort_by_name(){
    printf("%d\n", counter);

    int i=0, j=0;
    patient *temp;

    for(;j<=counter;j++){
        for(;i<counter-1;i++){

            if(strcmp(pRecords[i]->name, pRecords[i+1]->name) > 0){

                temp = pRecords[i];
                pRecords[i] = pRecords[i+1];
                pRecords[i+1]=temp;

            }//if loops

        }//2nd for loop

    }//1st for loop

}


counter-- number of records in the system.
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger on a small dataset?  Have you tried adding some printf statements to display the values of intermediate values?  Could you provide an example dataset that fails?

Comment: FYI, you probably want "strcoll" for alphabetization, since "strcmp" just compares bytes and doesn't understand alphabetical order. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcoll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your specific problem is that you're not re-initialising `i` to 0 each time you start the inner loop.

This is a relatively simple bubblesort where the inner loop runs over the list of `N` items, `N` times (controlled by the outer loop) to get them sorted. But *your* inner loop runs over them once then seems to go off elsewhere, beyond the end of the array. That's unlikely to provide useful results :-)

Your more general issue is: why are you not using the language facilities to do this, specifically `qsort`? If you're trying to educate yourself on sorting, that's fine, but if you just want to sort, there's little point re-inventing the wheel.

For what it's worth, I prefer the following algorithm in bubble sort. It stops early if the list is sorted and it doesn't look at already sorted items:

```
void sort_by_name(){
    int i, didSwap = 1, limit = numitems - 1;
    patient *temp;

    while (didSwap) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (strcmp (pRecords[i]->name, pRecords[i+1]->name) > 0) {
                temp          = pRecords[i];
                pRecords[i]   = pRecords[i+1];
                pRecords[i+1] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        limit--;
    }
}
```

The `didSwap` variable controls when to exit. If you traverse the entire unsorted section without swapping then obviously, you're finished. The `limit` controls that unsorted section and reduces gradually since, after each pass, there's a greater already-sorted section at the end of the list (the higher elements bubble up to the end of the list, one per pass).

Comment: You do not need to initialize i to 0 in the inner loop. Everything from 0 to j is already sorted. So you can start i from j.

Comment: Himadri, that is true.  But let us not obscure the important point: one must initialize i to *something* in the inner loop.

Comment: @Heath. I'm not trying to obscure the point about initializing i. I agree with that as I posted before. But, why not go the extra step and have a more efficient algorithm by setting i=j instead of i=0?

Comment: i tried to do qsort, but i couldn't figure out how to use it. Since pRecords is a struct containing string, floats/int

Comment: Himadri, you cannot start it at j because the elements bubble to the end of the list, not the start. After the first pass, array[max-1] is correct but array[0] may not be. The loop would have to run from 0 to max-2 in the next iteration, not 1 to max-1.

Comment: @user373466, that's okay, it's something you'll have to learn eventually but bubblesort, despite being maligned, is sometimes useful. Just be aware it doesn't scale well to large data sets.

Comment: @paxdiablo: give me an example where it's useful

Comment: @yi_H: In languages that don't provide a sort function, for small data sets, it's much quicker to bang up a bubble sort than anything else. It's also very fast on data that's already mostly sorted.

Comment: @yi_H: Case in point, I did an accounting spreadsheet once where transactions were added at the bottom, mostly in order but sometimes there would be one from a few weeks back. Transactions were multi-row so regular row-based sort wouldn't do the job. I put together a bubble sort for that in about half an hour (most of that was the multi-row stuff rather than the sort itself). It was basically the code in my answer but with each pass going in opposite directions (pass 1 forward, pass 2 backward, ...) to efficiently bubble things in both directions.

Comment: Insertion sort is also dead simple and at least performs better.

Comment: @Himadri - My point was that it is better to teach the basics and unimportant to teach the optimization.  Sometimes, for example in pedagogy, less material has greater effect than more material.  "Less is more."

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's true regarding your point about elements of the array bubbling to the end of the string instead of the beginning. But, that can be easily fixed by making the inner loop count down instead of up. For example: for(i=counter-1; i>j; i--). Just trying to point out that there is a pretty easy way to get a 2x improvement in speed, I agree that your original fix works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement bubble sort. The loop count variables seem to be a bit off.

```
        for(;i<counter-1;i++){
```

should be

```
        for(i=counter-2;i>=j; i--){
```

You must reset the i after every iteration of the 'j' loop. And work backwards to have the smallest number bubble up to the front.